# Disable Installed Software & Installation History tab on Help | About | Installation Details

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Is there some way I can suppress or disable the "Installed Software" & "Installation History" tabs on Help | About | Installation Details button in a RCP?

I'm not using P2 for this particular application so there will never be any history and the installed software tab has no content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the `org.eclipse.p2.ui` plugin's & features from my built product.

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want these do show then make sure that the following plug-ins are not deployed in your application's target platform:

```
org.eclipse.p2.ui
org.eclipse.p2.ui.discovery
org.eclipse.p2.ui.sdk
org.eclipse.p2.ui.updatechecker
```

Strictly speaking you only really need to remove the first bundle in the above list as the subsequent bundles depend on the core ui bundle. Typically, if I do not want the user to shcedule updates etc. I'll only inlcude the first bundle above. I then build a custom UI around p2 functionality whilst re-using some of the provided core p2 UI API (but without auto-scheduling UI etc. included).

If you want to remove the preference pages for the p2 sheduling/updates, then in your in your `WorkbenchAdvisor` you can use write the following in the `postStartup()` method:

> PreferenceManager pm =
>   PlatformUI.getWorkbench(
>   ).getPreferenceManager();
>
> pm.remove("org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.ProvisioningPreferencePage"); pm.remove("org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.preferences.MainPreferencePage");

Comment: I kind of figured this is what I needed to do ... the odd thing is, I don't have any 'org.eclipse.p2.ui' plug-in's or features listed for my application.  They seem to be be automatically being included when I run my build.

Answer (score -1):

subclass the AboutDialog class and override the createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite) method :)
and use your own InstallationDialog subclass.

to avoid displaying the tabs you don't want you have to override the createFolderItems method.

give a look the loadElements method to understand how this part of the dialog works.

Comment: I assume you're referring to org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog, which is an internal class.

Comment: Yes, I think that eclipse doesn't offer many ways to customize this dialog

Comment: How would I register my own class as the applications aboutbox?  Or would I have my own menu item that launches my custom about box dialog class?

Comment: you should register your own command that lauces your about dialog :)